# How to catch exception from MPMoviePlayerController: "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

Tags: xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

We have an app where we stream content from a 3rd party using MPMoviePlayerController. Sometimes they list the stream as available even though it is not setup yet. The problem is that when we try to play such a stream we get the error:

"An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

If we play the various sample streams like the one from Apple, it works great: 
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Is there a proper way to handle these errors from the MPMoviePlayerController?

There are various other posts on Stackoverflow concerning the same issue, but the various solutions is just removing the faulty streams. That is not possible in our case, we need to handle this at the client side... if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by disposing of the MPMoviePlayerController when I got the finished event. Then it no longer crashed so I hope this is the correct way of doing this...

```
            notification = MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications
            .ObservePlaybackDidFinish((sender, args) => {
                mp.Dispose();
                mp = null;
                if(notification != null)
                {
                    notification.Dispose();
                    notification = null;
                }
        });
```